Proof for Fresnel coefficient relation, $t't=1-r^2$
While solving an exercise about flux energy where we have a plane wave of light incident from air into a planeparallel glass with angle $\theta_i$, then transmitted inside it with angle $\theta_t$ and then transmitted again into air, the professor used this relation, but we never proved it in class:
$$t't=1-r^2,$$
where $t'$ is the transmission coefficient for when light is transmitted again into air, $t$ the same but for when it is transmitted inside the glass, and $r$ is the reflexion coefficient for when incident light reflects on the glass outer surface. Note this is valid for parallel and perpendicular coefficients. I tried proving it by substituting the explicit expressions of those coefficients that depend on $\theta_i$, $\theta_t$, $\theta_i'=\theta_t$, and $\theta_t'=\theta_i$, but came to a dead end...
